# Are the hypothesis of this theorem correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to put separation of variables in a formal ground.

I can show the following:

**Theorem.** Let $f: I_1\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g: I_2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be two continuous functions in the intervals $I_1, I_2\subset \mathbb R$. Let $I_0\subset I_2$ be an interval in which $g$ never vanishes. If $F: I_1\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $G: I_0\rightarrow \mathbb R$ are primitives of $f$ and $1/g$, then any differentiable function

$$x: I\rightarrow \mathbb R$$

such that $I\subset I_1$ is an interval, $x(I)\subset I_0$ and $G\circ x: I\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a primitive of $f$ is solution for the ODE

$$x^\prime(t)=f(t)g(x(t)).$$

**Proof.** In fact, the hypothesis ensure

$$f(t)=(G\circ x)^\prime(t)=G^\prime(x(t))x^\prime(t))=\frac{1}{g(x(t))}x^\prime(t)$$

so that

$$x^\prime(t)=f(t)g(x(t))$$

for every $t\in I$.

**Remark.** The hypothesis $g$ never vanishes in $I_0$ ensures $1/g$ is continuous in $I_0$ and therefore exists a primitive $G: I_0\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

But, is there really a differentiable function $x: I\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that:

- $I\subset I_1$;
- $x(I)\subset I_0$;
- $G\circ x: I\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a primitive of $f$?

So I'd like to answer this question. I thought of the following:

**Theorem.** Let $f: I_1\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g: I_2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be two continuous functions in the intervals $I_1, I_2\subset \mathbb R$. Let $I_0\subset I_2$ be an interval in which $g$ never vanishes. If $G: I_0\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a primitive of $1/g$, then

$$G: I_0\rightarrow G(I_0)$$

is a $C^1$ bijection onto the interval $G(I_0)$. Furtheremore, if $F: I_1\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a primitive of $f$ and $F^{-1}(G(I_0))\neq \phi$, then there is an interval $I\subset F^{-1}(G(I_0))$ such that $I\subset I_1$ and the function $x: I\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by

$$x(t)=G^{-1}(F(t))$$

is a solution for

$$x^\prime(t)=f(t)g(x(t))$$

in $I$.

Is this statement really correct? More precisely, are the hypothesis really correct?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of introducing $I_2$ only to drop it immediately in favor of $I_0$ and make no use of it again? Why not just make $I_0$ the domain of $g$ and require $g \ne 0$ on it?

Comment: You can use `\emptyset` $\emptyset$ or `\varnothing` $\varnothing$ to represent the empty set. $\phi$ is a very poor substitute.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify *open* intervals, then this is correct.

The only connected sets in $\Bbb R$ are intervals (or single points, if you do not consider those to be intervals). And the continuous image of a connected set is a connected set. Thus the continuous image of an interval is itself an interval.

$G$ is $C^1$ by assumption. Since $\frac 1g$ is continuous and never $0$, it is either strictly $> 0$ or strictly $< 0$, so $G$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, and thus must be injective. Further, if $I_0$ is *open*, then so must be $G(I_0)$. If $y \in F(I_1) \cap G(I_0)$, then there is some interval $(y-\delta, y+\delta)$ about $y$ in $G(I_0)$. $F^{-1}((y-\delta, y+\delta))$ is an open subset of the open interval $I_1$, and so it must contain some open interval about each pre-image of $y$. $I$ can be chosen as any of those open intervals.

Since I exists, the rest follows from the definition of $x$ on it.